# Prevent Maven from removing $ (dollar sign) from archetype resources?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I have a Maven archetype with some .java files. Inside them I perform some tests that need to use $ to evaluate json with json-path, e.g.:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
```

When I generate the project with mvn archetype:generate, the dollar is no longer present:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath(".id", is(1)))
```

Is there any way to tell Maven not to remove that $?

I've tried escaping in different ways: \$ - $$ - \$...without success.

I've noticed that **the $ sign is only removed when it's followed by a dot and some text**:

- $$ stays $$
- $. stays $
- $.text changes into .text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of a workaround, but you can do:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$"+".id", is(1)))
```

to prevent maven from removing it.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use this syntax:

```
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )

.andExpect(jsonPath("${symbol_dollar}.id", is(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try